# How do I start jhipster microservices locally in dev mode?

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry, jhipster-gateway

I generated my first microservices with JHipster. For this I used the jdl file listed below. Now I want to start the services locally.

For this I execute the following commands:

```
docker-compose -f myApp\src\main\docker\jhipster-registry.yml up -d

cd myApp

mvnw
```

It seems that I am not considering something basic. Because I get the following error message:

```
:: JHipster ?  :: Running Spring Boot 2.5.5 ::
:: https://www.jhipster.tech ::

2021-10-25 18:05:34.817  INFO 13520 --- [           main] com.myapp.MyApp                          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: dev,api-docs
2021-10-25 18:05:38.855 DEBUG 13520 --- [           main] i.g.r.utils.RxJava2OnClasspathCondition  : RxJava2 related Aspect extensions are not activated, because RxJava2 is not on the classpath.
2021-10-25 18:05:38.904 DEBUG 13520 --- [           main] i.g.r.utils.RxJava2OnClasspathCondition  : RxJava2 related Aspect extensions are not activated, because RxJava2 is not on the classpath.
2021-10-25 18:05:38.951 DEBUG 13520 --- [           main] i.g.r.utils.RxJava2OnClasspathCondition  : RxJava2 related Aspect extensions are not activated, because RxJava2 is not on the classpath.
2021-10-25 18:05:38.994 DEBUG 13520 --- [           main] i.g.r.utils.RxJava2OnClasspathCondition  : RxJava2 related Aspect extensions are not activated, because RxJava2 is not on the classpath.
2021-10-25 18:05:39.024 DEBUG 13520 --- [           main] i.g.r.utils.RxJava2OnClasspathCondition  : RxJava2 related Aspect extensions are not activated, because RxJava2 is not on the classpath.
2021-10-25 18:05:41.654  WARN 13520 --- [           main] onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration' defined in file [C:\Users\kleinoth\IdeaProjects\JHipster\microservicesTest\myApp\target\classes\com\myapp\config\SecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService' defined in file [C:\Users\kleinoth\IdeaProjects\JHipster\microservicesTest\myApp\target\classes\com\myapp\security\DomainUserDetailsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.myapp.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableR2dbcRepositories declared on DatabaseConfiguration: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#7b7cf475' of type [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFragmentsFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'repositoryFragments'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7b7cf475': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepositoryInternalImplFragment': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userRepositoryInternalImpl' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepositoryInternalImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\kleinoth\IdeaProjects\JHipster\microservicesTest\myApp\target\classes\com\myapp\repository\UserRepositoryInternalImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'r2dbcDatabaseClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/r2dbc/ConnectionFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'r2dbcDatabaseClient' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/r2dbc/ConnectionFactoryConfigurations$Pool.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.r2dbc.pool.ConnectionPool]: Factory method 'connectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create a ConnectionFactory for 'ConnectionFactoryOptions{options={driver=h2, protocol=file, database=./target/h2db/db/myapp;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1, host=., user=myApp}}'. Available drivers: [ postgresql, pool ]
2021-10-25 18:05:41.763 ERROR 13520 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

It seems that the gateway application cannot connect to the H2 database. Shouldn't at least the gateway application be running? Does anyone know what I'm missing?

The JDL file:

```
application {
  config {
    baseName myApp,
    applicationType gateway,
    packageName com.myapp,
    serverPort 8080,
    authenticationType jwt,
    prodDatabaseType postgresql,
    clientFramework angularX
  }
  entities *
}

application {
  config {
    baseName myApp1,
    applicationType microservice,
    packageName com.myapp,
    serverPort 8081,
    authenticationType jwt,
    prodDatabaseType postgresql,
  }
  entities A, B
}

application {
  config {
    baseName myApp2,
    applicationType microservice,
    packageName com.myapp,
    serverPort 8082,
    authenticationType jwt,
    prodDatabaseType postgresql,
  }
  entities C
}

entity A {
    name String
}

entity B {
    location String
}

entity C {

}

entity D {}

relationship OneToMany {
  A to B
}
```

Update: It only affects the gateway application. All microservices are running and recognized in the registry.

Dependencies in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Seems like you're missing the h2 jdbc driver. Could you check your pom.xml for the dependency?
"Unable to create a ConnectionFactory for 'ConnectionFactoryOptions{options={driver=h2, protocol=file, database=./target/h2db/db/myapp;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1, host=., user=myApp}}'. Available drivers:
 [ postgresql, pool ]"

Comment: yes. I updated it in the question.

Comment: Remove the scope. This should fix it.